# What does completing bonus challenge on a missions do?

Tags: warframe

What does it award to completing the challenges that you get during missions?

I have spotted it popping up for killing unaware enemies, weapon kills, head shots, collecting things etc.

[image]

I have spotted the pop up for completing them a couple of times but I still havent found out what the reward is for doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Warframe wiki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity#Bonus_Objectives_.28Challenges.29) would suggest that completing a bonus objective will net you an additional 500 affinity. These bonus objectives appear to be assigned randomly at the beginning of a mission.

Answer (score 4):

A. Still's answer is no longer correct. As of a recent update, the reward for achieving a bonus goal varies and is displayed at the bottom of the screen when the requirements are met.

I'll try to get a screenshot of this once I get home -- can't access Warframe from work.